# How can I implement simultaneous login feature in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I made a Flask app using `flask-login` and `flask-sqlalchemy`.

When I run my app and **login with the same user id in more then 2 devices or different browsers**, It fails and renders `Internal Server Error`.

But I want to make this simultaneous. When somebody log in with the user credentials as the same of somebody current, I don't want anybody to logout or face an error but to **share the same user**.

How can I make this?

If this is impossible, I want to **inform the first-logged-in-user**(like "your session was terminated because another user logged in with users" or something). Any hints or examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might lie within your custom login code. You can attach your code to the question or try using the code supplied in the documentation:

https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-example

Comment: I'm sorry to check this late :) Thanks for your answer! I think this helped